# PHP: Set Option of Select

Tags: php, html-select

I've tried a lot to retain the selected option value on all pages which we browse but I didn't succeed :(

Can any one figure out my code what went wrong here ??

```
<form name="area_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" >
<?php

    $sql = "select *from city";
    $loop = mysql_query($sql)
    or die ('cannot run the query because: ' . mysql_error());       
echo "<select name='areaa' onchange='window.location.href=this.value'>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop)) 
{
if($_POST['areaa']==$row['area']) 
    {
     echo "<option selected  VALUE=\"http://example.com\">".$row['area']."</option>"; 
    }
     else
     { 
     echo "<option  VALUE=\"http://example.com\">".$row['area']."</option>";
     } 
}
 echo "</select>"; 

?>
```

Comment: what issue you are facing

Comment: actually I am trying to stay on same page depending upon the selected option value, but when I select option I come with 1 option selected instead which i selected previous page ..

Comment: hope you get exact idea here 
http://muchmore.url.ph/samepage.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: I can retrieve the database value and populate it on OPTION only the problem is that i can't show the selected option to next page (here i used PHP_SELF).

Comment: To be honest, I can't fully understand what you want to be done. By selecting value user must be redirected to some page? What page, from selected option? If so, you must set `value` attribute in option, for now you always use **http://example.com** as value (Replace `VALUE=\"http://example.com\"` with `value='".$row['area']."'`) and submit form on select: use `document.forms.area_form.submit()` in `<select>` `onchange` attribute.

Comment: yah, i tried with that too.

echo "<select name='areaa'  onchange='document.forms.forme.submit()'>";    

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($loopp)) 
{

if($_POST['areaa']==$row['area']) 
{
 echo "<option selected  VALUE=\"http://example.com/<?php echo " ".$row['area'].".php"; ?> \">".$row['area']."</option>"; 
}
 else
 { 
 echo "<option  VALUE=''>".$row['area']."</option>";
 } 

}

 echo "</select>";   Here assuming that $row['area'] have names of city like "bangalore, delhi, mumbai " so after that .php extension...

Comment: Did you replace `VALUE=\"http://example.com\"` with `value='".$row['area']."'` ? I ran this code on my machine and options were selected properly on page reload.

Comment: yes,  I placed value='".$row['area']."' when I refresh or onchange it comes to 1st option :(  ,,,,............ what i want is, when i click on some option it should be selected to while browsing, but it is not happening :( ,,,,,,,,,,, http://www.muchmore.url.ph/samepage.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$areaa = isset($_POST['areaa'])?$_POST['areaa']:"";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop)) 
{

 echo "<option  VALUE=\"http://example.com\" $areaa==\"http://example.com\"?'selected=selected' : ''  >".$row['area']."</option>"; 
     echo "<option  VALUE=\"http://example2.com\" $areaa==\"http://example2.com\"?'selected=selected' : '' >".$row['area']."</option>";

}
```

Comment: Gender: <select name="gender"> 
    <option value=" "> Not Selected </option> 
    <option value="Male"<?=$g == "Male" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>Male</option> 
    <option value="Female"<?=$g == "Female" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>Female</option> 
</select>

Comment: so when i click on kolkatta its again coming back to bangalore :(